# Added SDL librairy : "GNUC is not defined as a preprocessor macro" when building with VS

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdl, unreal-engine4

I've created a UE4 plugin that uses the SDL librairy. However, when I try to use

```
#include "SDL.h"
```

I get this error:

```
Error   C4668   '__GNUC__' is not defined as a preprocessor macro, replacing with '0' for '#if/#elif'
```

Those errors point me to two files : SDL_assert.h and begin_code.h - both files are from the SDL librairy.

I think that it has to do with the compiler, here's a snippet of code at line 37 of begin_code.h (the actual error line) :

```
#  if (__GNUC__ >= 4)  /* technically, this arrived in gcc 3.1, but oh well. */
```

I don't think VS uses gcc to compile, that may be the issue.
Any idea of how I can fix that ?

Comment: Get in touch with the developer and ask him if the plugin supports VS.

Comment: Warning level 4 is unusable as it prevents 100% legitimate code from compiling. This is one of these cases. Drop to 3.

Comment: warning level 3, 2,1 or 0 didn't solve it. 
I actually needed to replace 
`#  if (__GNUC__ >= 4)` 
by 
`#  if defined(__GNUC__) &&__GNUC__ >= 4`
Thanks anyway for the lead

Comment: Hmm it looks like something is wrong here. C4668 is off by default, so not even /W4 would trigger it. Try it on a fresh project and see for yourself. Maybe something in your project specifically turns this warning on.

Comment: If you explicitly disable the warning just before the include, it does the trick for me: `#pragma warning(disable: 4668)`.